# How to select a dropdown menu using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I'm working on a personal project, trying to use selenium to web scrape my locals teams results from a website. The site has three drop-down lists, at the moment I'd be happy to just be able to alter one. The code below clicks reject cookies when I enter the page, that's what the WebDriver line does. I'm getting as far as 'dropdown' and then an error that no such element exists. I've tried CSS_SELECTOR, XPATH and all the other options to no avail. I am only new to this so it could be something simple I'm missing but I've read a lot of the previous forums with similar questions and the answers didn't work for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.leinsterrugby.ie/domestic-rugby/domestic-fixtures-results/")

time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='onetrust-reject-all-handler']"))).click()
time.sleep(3)

dropdown=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="groups_data"]')
time.sleep(5)
dropdown.select_by_value('5756')

driver.quit() # close browser
```

Comment: _The code below clicks reject cookies_: At my end the cookie popup remains folded and doesn't expands. Isn't it the expected behaviour at your end?

Comment: _I'm getting as far as 'dropdown'_: With which dropdown are you trying to interact?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with dropdown options as *`Men`*, *`Schools`*, *`Women`*, *`Youth`* is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.leinsterrugby.ie/domestic-rugby/domestic-fixtures-results/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='https://shared2.sportsmanager.ie/~leinsterrugby/']")))
    Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name=user]")))).select_by_value('7183')
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://shared2.sportsmanager.ie/~leinsterrugby/']")))
    Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='user']")))).select_by_value('7183')
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: leinsterrugby]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah my issue was that I wasn't aware it was in an iframe, thanks so much your answer is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Many of those lines can be simplified by using [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase).

Here's code that searches for results on that site and then prints the results: (`self.switch_to_frame()` is needed to switch to the iframe, and `self.select_option_by_text()` is for the dropdowns.)

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class RugbyResultsTests(BaseCase):
    def test_get_rubgy_results(self):
        self.open("https://www.leinsterrugby.ie/domestic-rugby/domestic-fixtures-results/")
        self.switch_to_frame('iframe[src*="sportsmanager.ie/~leinsterrugby/"]')
        self.sleep(1)
        self.select_option_by_text("select#usercompyear", "2020-2021")
        self.sleep(3)
        self.select_option_by_text("select#groups_data", "Leinster Seconds League (J2)")
        self.sleep(1)
        self.click('a[href*="sportsmanager.ie/~leinsterrugby/league/155189"]')
        self.sleep(2)
        print("\n" + self.get_text("table.table-condensed"))
```

Output: (After running the above test with `pytest` with `seleniumbase` installed via `pip`.)

```
POS TEAM PLD W D L PF PA DIFF BP BP L DED PTS
1 Ashbourne 1 1 0 0 18 17 1 0 0 0 4
2 Gorey 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
3 Kilkenny 1 0 0 1 17 18 -1 1 1 0 1
4 Suttonians 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 Monkstown 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 Seapoint 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 Bective Rangers 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 Dundalk 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The default browser for [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) tests is Chrome, but you can change that by calling `pytest --firefox`.

Comment: Thanks, your output looks great. I've never even heard of seleniumbase and haven't done   a lot of pytest so I'm not sure where to start on your solution. But I appreciate how good your answer looks.